# Can I directly substitute a specific complex number into a formal power series equation?

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

Suppose there is a formal power series equation, such as
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j x^j\right)^i.$$

If there is a complex number $r$ which makes $\sum c_jr^j$ and $\sum a_i r^i$ convergent, also, the convergent point of $\sum c_jr^j$, $s$, makes $\sum b_i s^i$ convergent, then, does the equation above still hold when I substitute $r$ into $x$?

Thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation involves re-arranging the power series.  Hence this can only be done if the respective sums converge absolutely.  This is satisfied if the power series is evaluated at a value from *inside* the respective radius of convergence.

If a power series just converges conditionally, then re-arranging might change its value.  This can only happen if the value where the series is evaluated is on the boundary of the radius of convergence.

See also [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

There are also some posts on mathoverflow that deal with value-preserving permutations of conditionally convergent series, like [The stabilizer of the conditionally convergent series](https://mathoverflow.net/q/263399).

---

**ad comment:** Just that a function is analytic at some point doesn't tell you anything about it's power series expansion.  Take $u(z) = \sum_0 z^n$ for example, with radius of convergence $r_u=1$. $u$ is analytic everywhere except $z=1$, but the series does not converge for any $|z|>1$.  And it does not converge for, say, $z=-1$ or $z=\sqrt{-1}$, either.

Also, if a power series expansion of $f$ around 0 converges for $z$ with $|z|=r_f$, then $f$ is countinuous at $z$.  Again, the opposite is not true in general, and continuiuty of $f$ doesn't tell you anything about $r_f$ or about the becaviour of a power series expansion.

However, your requirement that $f$ is analytic in$^1$ $0\leqslant |z|\leqslant r_f$ for $f\in\{F,G,H\}$ means that the radius of convergence of $f$ is *greater* than $r_f$ and $r_f$ does *not* denote the radius of convergence of $f$.  The reason is that, when a power series has a finite radius of convergence $r_f\neq0$, then $f$ has a singularity of some sort for at least one $|z|=r_f$.  Example is polylog $\operatorname{Li}_2(z) = \sum_1 z^n/n^2$ that converges for all $|z|=1$ but it has still a singularity: a [branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) at $z=1$.

The conclusion is that you are *inside*$^1$ the radius of convergence of the functions, thus their power series converge absolutely.

Notice that $z$ above denotes a complex number, and if you replace it by a real number, then what's said above is no more true.  For example, $\arctan z =\sum_0 z^{2n+1}/(2n+1)$ is analytic over $\Bbb R$, yet the power series has finite radius of convergence $r_{\arctan} = 1$.  The reason is that $\arctan$ has branch points at $z=\pm\sqrt{-1}$, so you only see whan't going on over $\Bbb C$.

---

$^1$Assuming with $D(z,r)$ you denote the *closed* disk of radius $r$ around $z$.

If, however, $D$ denotes the open disk and $r_f$ stands actually for the respective radius of convergence, then analyticity of $f$ in the open disk $0\leqslant |z| < r_f$ does not tell about whether the power series converges (absolutely) for some $|z|=r_f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Allow me to ask more. The equation I mentioned above seems like composite functions, $F(G(x))= H(x)$ and $G(0)=0$. If $F$, $G$ and $H$ is respectively analytic in $D(0,r_1)$, $D(0,r_2)$ and $D(0,r_2)$, $F$ and $H$ are continue on the boundary of their analytic domain, and $|G(x)|\leq r_1$, can I conclude that $F(G(r))=H(r)$ for $r\in D(0,r_2)$ is equavalent to the power series equation $\sum b_i(\sum c_j r^j)^i=\sum a_i r^i$?

Comment: @zyynankai. I edited the answer accordingly.